# CRM Mobile Forms

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to use crm mobile application.Can anyone tell me where to write  the javascript for the mobile forms.
I have added the javascript code in the main we  form's js but it is not being called when opening the mobile form from browser.Does the js only work when opened from a crm mobile app?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you referenced the web resource containing the script from your mobile form?

Answer (score 2):

Depends which app you're talking about.

**CRM for Phones and Tablets**

- supports scripting ([reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531159.aspx))
- uses the same scripts and form definitions that your desktop browser uses (though the UI is quite different) that are used when you visit CRM in your desktop browser, no special configuration necessary to get the JS to work.

**CRM for Phones Express**

- doesn't support scripting ([reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531080.aspx)).
- this app displays forms of type "Mobile - Express"

**Opening CRM with the browser on your mobile device**

- In 2016, CRM will load just like it does on your desktop, with scripting (assuming your mobile browser is standards compliant).
- In 2013, I believe a different version of CRM would load, but finding information about it is really confusing because of the name changes Microsoft has recently made to the phone apps.